# How to make hover last longer

Tags: css, hover

I'm having a photo, that dims when hovered but immediately turns normal when mouse is not on the photo. Is it possible to make the dimness last for a few seconds longer after removing the mouse from the picture in CSS? Maybe an animation?

Sorry for a weird desctiption, English is not my first language and I'm just a beginner :)

Comment: The first step to get concrete help would be supply us with the essential code in order to troubleshoot it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `transition` property for the animations. There are [tons of transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) which you may use on any state of your html element.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
.yourElement{
transition: all 3s ease-in-out;
opacity: 1;
}
.yourElement:hover{
opacity: .5;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/EdgarAlexPoe/v2zkja0u/

Just adjust the timing (3s) to however long you want your transition duration to be.